# How can I apply a single value to all kwarg values?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a class that takes in `kwargs` and defaults to `True` if the `kwarg` does not exist.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):    
        self.kwarg_one = kwargs.get('kwarg_one', True)
        self.kwarg_two = kwargs.get('kwarg_two', True)
```

`MyClass` is a parent class that will be inherited from a subclass

```
class MyOtherClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubclassOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

In `MyClass`, `kwarg_one` and `kwarg_one` will contain `boolean` values that will load specific information that most sub classes will use, but some sub classes will not need to load the information. In this case, I can pass in `False` for the specific `kwarg` I do not need to load.

```
moc = MyOtherClass(kwarg_one=False)
```

In other case, I will have classes that still require to inherent `MyClass`, but does not need to load any of the information the parent class loads.

```
moc = MyOtherClass(kwarg_one=False, kwarg_two=False)
```

Having only two `kwargs` is not bad, but I foresee `MyClass` accepting multiple arguments and it may become grueling to have to pass `False` into 10+ arguments.

Is there a way to pass in `False` once so that all `kwargs` are `False`?

Comment: If I understood it right, you could use on MyClass __init__(self, arg_one=False, arg_two=False, **kwargs), can't you? You could also use a default config dict, with all the default values set to false and use the update method with kwargs as arguments, thus overriden the default values with the ones set in kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dict.fromkeys` to build a new `dict` with the keys from an iterable and given value.

```
moc = MyOtherClass(**dict.fromkeys(('kwarg_one', 'kwarg_two'), False))
```